Alien invasion with black little gleaming stones
Does anyone remember the name of that 90's - 00's movie, I think it's a pretty long one where the alien invasion starts with a meteorite rain, it scatters black shiny little stones everywhere and people who take them in their hands get bitten and infected and mind controled. A small surviving group go hide in the desert and try to research how to cure the plague. The main character transforms into an alien near the end and leads the mind controlled humans.

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

This was the tv miniseries Invasion, with Luke Perry as the first infectee and main coordinator of the "virus" invasion efforts (which was carried by the little black stones, and injected whoever touched them), and eventually mutated or transformed by it.

i think that's it thanks unfortunately i can't find it anywhere
